# How to terminate program if value of 0 or anything over .001 is inputted

Tags: javascript

So I know using a while loop like this `while ((value = input.nextDouble()) != 0)` makes it so when 0 is inputted the program terminates and the print statements are printed, but how would I make it so that if anything less than .001 or 0 makes the program terminate?

Comment: `while ((value = input.nextDouble()) > 0.001) `

Comment: That wouldn't work because I also want to be able to read in negative numbers

Comment: Then you need to rephrase your question, because it is unclear what you want. Do you want to terminate for values between 0.001 and 0?

Comment: if so, the one-liner is `while ((value = input.nextDouble()) > 0.001 || value < 0)`

Comment: I want the program to terminate if 0 is entered or any number closer than .001 away from zero.

Comment: alright, will write up a quick answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a quick function for checking if a number is within a threshold of 0:

(this differs from my previous comment in that it will check if the value is within the threshold, but negative)

```js
function isNearZero(num) {
  const threshold = 0.001;
  return num < threshold && num > -threshold;
}

while (!isNearZero(value = input.nextDouble())) {
  // do things
}
```